# Find the condition that the second degree equation $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ represent a rectangular hyperbola.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the condition that the second degree equation $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ represent a rectangular hyperbola.

---

I know that the condition is $abc + 2fgh - af^2 - bg^2 - ch^2 \ne 0,h^2>ab,a+b=0$.But i dont know how to prove it.
I have read one proof on some website but it is proved by Eigen values and Eigen vectors.I could not understand that.
Is there any other method to prove this?Please help.

Comment: Hint: the first two conditions tell you that the equation represents a nondegenerate hyperbola. The last is related to the desired relation between its asymptotes.

Comment: See  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations of the asymptotes, as they are perpendicular lines, can be written in general as:
$$
\alpha x+\beta y +\gamma=0
\quad\text{and}\quad
\beta x-\alpha y +\delta=0.
$$
The equation of the hyperbola can then be written as
$$
(\alpha x+\beta y +\gamma)(\beta x-\alpha y +\delta)=\varepsilon,
$$
where $\varepsilon\ne0$ if the hyperbola is non-degenerate.
This equation can be expanded, and comparing it with your
$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ we find:
$$
a=-b=\alpha\beta,\quad 2h=\beta^2-\alpha^2,\quad
2g=\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma,\quad 2f=\beta\delta-\alpha\gamma,\quad
c=\gamma\delta-\varepsilon.
$$
The first equation is the same as your condition $a+b=0$, which then represents the perpendicularity of the asymptotes. From this it follows that $ab\le0$, and  condition $h^2>ab$ is then the same as stating that you cannot have $a=b=h=0$, for in that case the hyperbola would degenerate into a line.

The other condition for the hyperbola to be non-degenarate is $\varepsilon\ne0$, which can be written as $\gamma\delta-c\ne0$. But from the above relations we get
$$
\gamma=2{\beta g-\alpha f\over\alpha^2+\beta^2},\quad
\delta=2{\beta f+\alpha g\over\alpha^2+\beta^2},
$$
whence:
$$
\gamma\delta={4\alpha\beta(g^2-f^2)+4(\beta^2-\alpha^2)fg
\over(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^2}
={a(g^2-f^2)+2hfg
\over a^2+h^2}.
$$
Plugging the last result into $\gamma\delta-c\ne0$ we obtain
$$
a(g^2-f^2)+2hfg-(a^2+h^2)c\ne0,
$$
which is the same as your first condition, once you take into account that 
$a=-b$.